# Play audio html

Tags: javascript, html

how can i  play audio like its a notification.

as soon as the page is opened the notification audio starts beeping.

and it has to beep every 3 seconds

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <script>  
     var aSound = document.createElement('audio');
     aSound.setAttribute('src', '/path/beep.wav');
     aSound.play();
 </script>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>hello world</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Break this down into discrete steps. Can you  get a sound to play at all? There's lots of tutorials out there that show how to play sound on a web page. After that, can you get some JS code to run every 3 seconds? There's lots of tutorials out there that show how to do that. Then just put them together!

Comment: you should use **setInterval** function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem of your code is, that the audio element is never added to the DOM. By calling `document.createElement` you just create the element, but it is never added to your page.

To do so, you could use the following code line:

```js
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(aSound);
```

This will add the audio element to the end of the `body` element. However, you can only do this after the DOM has been created. Currently, your code is executed before any element exists at all. The code must wait until after the page is fully loaded.

To play the sound repeatedly, you can simply use `window.setInterval` if the audio file is less than three seconds long.

Below is a full example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <script>
            // Execute the code inside, after the page was loaded
            window.addEventListener("load", () => {
                var aSound = document.createElement('audio');
                aSound.setAttribute('src', '/path/beep.wav');
                // Append element to the DOM
                document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(aSound);
                aSound.play()
                // Execute the code inside every 3 seconds
                window.setInterval(() => {
                    aSound.play()
                }, 3000);
            })
            
        </script>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>hello world</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Keep in mind, that many browsers these days block autoplaying audio and video content. I had to allow this in Firefox for my test page, so this is not suitable for public pages.

Comment: yes sample worked for me, but the problem is playing it in all browsers. yes all browsers nolonger support autoplaying audio

Comment: Most browsers allow playing an audio or video only if triggered by user interaction, e.g. a button click or similar. Depending on your use case, this could work. I don't know what happens for repeated plays like in the example above. If it does not work, it could maybe be circumvented, by having an audio file that is longer than 3 seconds and simple resetting the playback time back to zero.  @JoeMike